# Populating a site template with dynamically updating files

Tags: content-type, site, file, template

I have created a site that I want to make into a template and deploy a copy of roughly once a week. I want each new site to contain a standard set of libraries and folders (I have those - fine so far), but I want to populate some of those folders with standard files. The files would derive from site content type templates. What I really want is for those files to feed dynamically from the content type template, so when I update the template then the corresponding file in a newly created site will reflect the update when it is generated.

Any ideas? I know it can be done as I've seen it, years ago in fact... I look forward to hearing from beings superior to myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in 1 of 2 ways. But I think the question is; which way do you prefer, and what are the requirements.

1. When you save the site as a template, you can [include content from libraries](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989#__what_gets_saved) to be saved in this template as well. This way the folders in your document libraries have standard files. But keep in mind that the size limit of a site saved as a template is 50MB.
2. On the site collection you deploy this site template to, you can [create an EventReceiver which will trigger on site provisioned](http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2010/10/07/how-to-attach-an-event-receiver-to-the-web-added-event-and-for-what-purpose/).
   Using this approach you will have to write custom code that imports the standard files you're talking about and add them to the folders in the document libraries. I would suggest this approach if you have files that would exceed the 50MB limit Site templates have.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I appreciate that. What I'm trying to do is populate the site libraries on creation of the site, as if the user had selected Document > New Document > {content type}, and therefore no matter when the content type template was updated, the new site will always be provisioned from the most up to date template - your option 1 won't achieve that, but will your option 2?

Comment: @MikeJ Sorry for the late answer; Yes, option 2 will achieve this. In your code you specify the Content Type to use. If the content type is up-to-date on the site collection, then the code will automatically use the latest version.